# Javascript Variable - initialize/math/store numerical value

Tags: javascript, regex, closures

My goal is to store a numeric value in a variable , secondly increment/decrement this value on a click event ,and at last use the value for styling purpose.

The function I came up with looks like this:

```
    function onButtonClick(e) {
    var rot = this.className.slice(5),
           rotaX,
           rotaY,
           rotationX,
           rotationY,
           step = 90;

    if( rot === 'up'){rotationX = rotaX - step}      /* {alert (rot);}//    //{rotationX -= step}// */
    else if (rot === 'down') {rotationX   = rotaX + step}
    else if (rot === 'right') {rotationY  = rotaY - step}
    else if (rot === 'left') {rotationY   = rotaX + step };

    var rotaX = rotationX ;
    var rotaY = rotationY;

    cubeRot.style.transform = "rotateX("+ rotationX +"deg) rotateY("+ rotationY +"deg)";


}
```

Evaluation and targeting the selector seems correct so the problem must be in how I'm summing/storing the values, the result is it doesn't return any value...

BTW any constructive advice regarding optimizing the syntax is welcome.

**Edit1**

originally I wasn't storing the value and the code was

```
var rotations = {
up: "rotateY(90deg)",
down: "rotateY(-90deg)",
left: "rotateX(90deg)",
right: "rotateX(-90deg)"
};
function onButtonClick(e) {
var rot = this.className.slice(5);
cubeRot.style.transform = rotations[rot];
 }
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class^='show-']")).forEach(function(el) {
el.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
})
```

**Edit2**

```
    var rotationX=0,
    rotationY=0;

function onButtonClick(e) {

       var rot = this.className.slice(5),
           step = 90;
    if( rot === 'up') {rotationX -= step}
    else if (rot === 'down') {rotationX   += step}
    else if (rot === 'right') {rotationY -= step }
    else if (rot === 'left') {rotationY  += step };

 cubeRot.style.transform = "rotateX("+ rotationX +"deg) rotateZ("+ rotationY +"deg)";
}
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class^='show-']")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
});
```

in this way variable `rotationX ,rotationY;` is stored correctly - `RotaX` and `RotaY` were useless

Comment: I'd use the `classList` property in conjunction with `contains()` to check for the class. Furthermore as `switch` statement might be more readable then multiple `if - else`.

Comment: Where are you getting the `rotax` and `rotay` values? You seem to be initialising them in the function but then try to use them in the calculation which will give you undefined +/ step.

Comment: RotaX is undefined  it doesn't get initialized.. I've also tried to use Parseint but still couldn't get it going

Comment: @Sirko I know syntax can be much better so I'll try it ...  but still this ugly version seems logical to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there are two main problems with your code:

1. The variables to capture the current state of the cube are not preserved between different calls of `onButtonClick()`.
2. You way of extracting the class is not that stable. There are plenty of ways, that this might go wrong.

The following code should solve both problems by using global variables for the state and the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) property to retrieve the classes.

```
// define the state outside to have it preserved between calls
var rotaX = 0,
    rotaY = 0;

function onButtonClick(e) {
    var klasses = this.classList,
        step = 90;

    if(       klasses.contains('up')    ){ rotaX -= step; }
    else if ( klasses.contains('down')  ){ rotaX += step; }
    else if ( klasses.contains('right') ){ rotaY -= step; }
    else if ( klasses.contains('left')  ){ rotaX += step; }

    cubeRot.style.transform = "rotateX("+ rotaX +"deg) rotateY("+ rotaY +"deg)";
}
```

As an alternative to introducing 2 new global variables (`rotax` and `rotay`) one could think about using [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) in `cubeRot` to store the current state.

PS: One possibly could drop the local variables `rotationX` and `rotationY`. You never seem to use them in a different way then `rotaX` and `rotaY`. But maybe some parts of the code got dropped for the example ...

---

**Edit**

I adjusted the function above, so that it is runnable on its own without any further code. See this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sirko/6f831wwg/).

You probably want to take a look at [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to keep the rotated element in the viewport.

Comment: I added rotaX and rotaY in a second moment , in the first place I tried  `if( rot === 'up'){rotationX -= step}` , I'm updating the code to show the exact starting point...

Comment: OK, since rotaX & Y were useless I ripped them out. Following your advice I initialized rotationX and Y outside, and it's now working !!! now I'm looking into integrating `Element.classList`(I'm editing question) . Could you explain why was my way of extracting the class was not stable ?

Comment: @maioman You rely on string operations. So you expect the class attribute to hold something like `"left"`. But in the future you might want to style the buttons using CSS classes, so you add another class `rotate` to the buttons. This might lead to a new `className` value of `"rotate left"`. You extracting of the first 5 characters would yield `"rotat"`, which breaks the `if`s as it matches no condition.